# can't access object's properties within object in react

Tags: reactjs

I can't seem to access data that's part of an object within an object. here I'm trying to access likes in profile which would otherwise be fine using vanilla javascript to print out this.state.data.profile.likes

```
class App extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: {}
        };
     }

     componentDidMount() {
         var x = {      
             "notifications": 12,
             "profile": {
                 "likes": 5
             }
         };
         this.setState({
             data: x
         });
     }


    render() {
        const {notifications, profile} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <span>Notifications {notifications}</span>
                <span>Likes {profile.likes}</span>
            </div>
        );
}
```

Comment: Aren't you getting the wrong info out of `this.state` in your `render` function? I think it would be `const { data } = this.state`

Comment: you're right. it should be using { data }

Answer (score 2):

Before mounting - and on the initial render - your state looks like this:

```
{
  data: {}
}
```

After mounting - on the second render - your state looks like this:

```
{
  data: {
    notifications: 12,
    profile: {
      likes: 5
    }
  }
}
```

You're trying to access `this.state.profile.likes` which doesn't exist. Presumably you mean to access `this.state.data.profile.likes` which does exist, but only on the second render.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this while also trying to fix the same problem. The constructor should be:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: {
            profile: {}
        }
    };
 }
```

**Always initialize objects within objects**

Comment: I had the same issue and this saved me! and yeah you will need to initialize each object, and since `profile` is another object you will need to initialize it too

Answer (score 0):

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting

render -> componentDidMount

put state data in constructor

Comment: It doesn't matter where you place it. As long as the function eventually gets called, it will end up on the DOM.

Comment: first - render;

second - componentDidMount;

this.state.profile.likes in render -- error

Comment: You can not access non-existent data. There is a violation of react lifecycle

Comment: Oh, you're right in that regard. Trying to access a key in `undefined`. But  I'm pretty sure that's not OPs error.

Comment: this was more so an example of using fetch in the mount to get data to populate it into setState so I wouldn't be putting the state data in the constructor. should i be using componentwillmount instead?